# PostgreSQL join two tables with LIMIT 1

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have two tables:

First table "persons"

```
id  |  name   |
---------------
1   |  peter  |
3   |  martin |
5   |  lucy   |
```

Second table "meetings"

```
id  |  date       | id_persons |
--------------------------------
1   |  2014-12-08 |     1      |
2   |  2013-05-10 |     2      |
3   |  2015-08-25 |     1      |
4   |  2016-10-18 |     1      |
5   |  2012-01-01 |     3      |
6   |  2016-09-28 |     5      |
```

I need somehow get only last date from "meeting" table for every person (or selected). And result table must be order by name. I thought, it could be like this, but WHERE clause in LEFT JOIN can't be used:

```
SELECT meetings.id, meetings.date, persons.name FROM persons
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT meetings.date, meetings.id, meetings.id_persons FROM
           meetings WHERE persons.id = meetings.id_persons ORDER BY
           meetings.date DESC LIMIT 1) m ON m.id_persons = persons.id 
WHERE persons.id < 6 ORDER BY persons.name
```

So I started with DISTINCT and it worked, but I think that it is not good idea:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON (persons.id) persons.id, persons.name, 
         m.date, m.id FROM persons
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT meetings.id, meetings.date, meetings.id_persons 
             FROM meetings ORDER BY meetings.date DESC) m 
             ON m.id_persons = persons.id
     WHERE persons.id < 6 ORDER BY persons.id) p 
ORDER BY p.name
```

Result what I need is:

```
name   |  date       | id_meetings
-----------------------------------
lucy   |  2016-09-28 |      6
martin |  2012-01-01 |      5
peter  |  2016-10-18 |      4
```

Could you help me with better solution?

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres, the easiest way is probably `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (p.id) p.*, m.*
from persons p left join
     meetings m
     on m.id_persons = p.id
order by p.id, m.date desc;
```

Note:  `distinct on` is specific to Postgres.

Comment: uh, that was fast:) thanks ... if I want to sort, it can be done only with second select? Like I wrote? SELECT * FROM (your select) p ORDER BY p.name? I used it on 10000 records (maximum count what will be in db) and it spend 420ms .. not too bad:)

Comment: If you want an additional sort, then a subquery and `order by` would be the way to go.